# Why the JSON response is not getting though echoing it?

Tags: php, json

I am using PHP for the server side of my android app. The app sends the login parameters **rollno** and **password** with `POST` method. The code is fetching the result and echoing the response with `JSON`. I have hosted the same system on the live server as well as on my localhost. The live server works fine, but the local server is not echoing the response. The code is as below:

```
// an array to display response
$response = array();
if (isset($_GET['apicall'])) {
    switch ($_GET['apicall']) {
    case 'login':
        // this part will handle the login
        // for login we need the email and password
        if (isTheseParametersAvailable(array(
            'rollno',
            'password'
        ))) {
            // getting server ip for building image url
            $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
            // image upload path
            define('UPLOAD_PATH', 'uploads/');
            // getting values
            $rollno = $_POST['rollno'];
            $user_password = $_POST['password'];
            $sql = "SELECT password from users WHERE rollno = \"$rollno\"";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $pass_hash = $row["password"];
            }
            if (password_verify($user_password, $pass_hash)) {
                // creating the query
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, gender, rollno, image, personal_notice FROM users WHERE rollno = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $rollno);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                // query for fetching fees records
                $feesqry = $conn->prepare("SELECT total, paid, remaining FROM fees WHERE rollno = ?");
                $feesqry->bind_param("s", $rollno);
                $feesqry->execute();
                $feesqry->store_result();
                // query for fetching attendance records
                $attqry = $conn->prepare("SELECT mon, tue, wed, thrs, fri, sat, sun FROM attendance WHERE rollno = ?");
                $attqry->bind_param("s", $rollno);
                $attqry->execute();
                $attqry->store_result();
                // query for fetching test records
                $tstqry = $conn->prepare("SELECT tst1_date, tst1_marks, tst1_rank, tst2_date, tst2_marks, tst2_rank, tst3_date, tst3_marks, tst3_rank, tst4_date, tst4_marks, tst4_rank, tst5_date, tst5_marks, tst5_rank FROM test WHERE rollno = ?");
                $tstqry->bind_param("s", $rollno);
                $tstqry->execute();
                $tstqry->store_result();
                // query for fetching common notice
                $noticeqry = $conn->prepare("SELECT common_notice FROM notice");
                $noticeqry->execute();
                $noticeqry->store_result();
                // if the user exist with given credentials
                if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                    $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $email, $gender, $rollno, $image_temp, $personal_notice);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $image = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/arsod_dynamic/' . UPLOAD_PATH . $image_temp;
                    $feesqry->bind_result($total, $paid, $remaining);
                    $feesqry->fetch();
                    $attqry->bind_result($mon, $tue, $wed, $thrs, $fri, $sat, $sun);
                    $attqry->fetch();
                    $tstqry->bind_result($tst1_date, $tst1_marks, $tst1_rank, $tst2_date, $tst2_marks, $tst2_rank, $tst3_date, $tst3_marks, $tst3_rank, $tst4_date, $tst4_marks, $tst4_rank, $tst5_date, $tst5_marks, $tst5_rank);
                    $tstqry->fetch();
                    $noticeqry->bind_result($common_notice);
                    $noticeqry->fetch();
                    $user = array(
                        'id' => $id,
                    // Various other key/values here
                    $response['user'] = $user;
                }
                else {
                    // if the user not found
                    $response['error'] = false;
                    $response['message'] = 'Invalid Roll No. or Password';
                }
            }
            else {
                // if the user not found
                $response['error'] = false;
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid Roll No. or Password';
            }
        }
        break;
        else {
            // if it is not api call
            // pushing appropriate values to response array
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
        }
        // displaying the response in json structure
        echo json_encode($response);
        // function validating all the paramters are available
        // we will pass the required parameters to this function
        function isTheseParametersAvailable($params)
        {
            // traversing through all the parameters
            foreach($params as $param) {
                // if the paramter is not available
                if (!isset($_POST[$param])) {
                    // return false
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // return true if every param is available
            return true;
        }
```

The above code has line `echo json_encode($response);` the also, `json` is not returned. Please help.

There is successful JSON output on the live server like this

```
{"error":false,"message":"Login successfull","user":{"id":498,"username":"Test Entry","email":null,"gender":"NA","rollno":1000,"image":"https:\/\/softglobe.net\/client-projects\/arsodclasses\/dynamic\/uploads\/default-pic.png","personal_notice":"Not available yet","common_notice":"Freedom in Mind;Faith in Words;Pride in our Heart; Memories in our Souls.Let\u2019s salute the Nation on Republic Day.HAPPY REPUBLIC DAY!","total":"-","paid":"-","remaining":"-","mon":"-","tue":"-","wed":"-","thrs":"-","fri":"-","sat":"-","sun":"-","tst1_date":"-","tst1_marks":"-","tst1_rank":"-","tst2_date":"-","tst2_marks":"-","tst2_rank":"-","tst3_date":"-","tst3_marks":"-","tst3_rank":"-","tst4_date":"-","tst4_marks":"-","tst4_rank":"-","tst5_date":"-","tst5_marks":"-","tst5_rank":"-"}}
```

But on the local server, nothing prints as a response.

Comment: I've formatted the code for you,

Comment: What happens instead? Should we read and debug all that code?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have updated the post with the json response returned from live server. On local serever, there's nothing printed.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this situation? What about XDebug, vardumps, error reporting, all that stuff?

Comment: @NicoHaase I just tried with `var_dump($response);`, but that is also not printed

Comment: There are some syntax errors there and also undefined variable. Are you sure it runs in production without errors? This code should throw errors. The reason nothing appears is cause there are php errors but you don't show them. You should enable error reporting in your code.

Comment: The point of debugging using `var_dump` would be not to check only a single variable, but to check which parts of that code are executed and why. If you don't want to use a more efficient debugger, put dumps before all conditions to check which one triggers

Answer (score 0):

you echoed response after the end of first switch case. echo before break statement

Comment: after break echo will not work. try to use inside break or outside switch statement